# How to instance objects on surface, aligned with UV direction?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I have simplified my task to this setup:

[image]

I want this compass needles to follow the UV, so that from one side of this C-shaped mesh needles will face red upwards, and on other side - blue will face upwards.

Here is the test file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like two samples, one with small offset can solve this problem:

[image]

Looks a bit hacky way for me, maybe someone will find more clever solution